# bottom overflowed by 125 pixcels

Tags: flutter

i want when the user click to float action button, then a bottom sheet opened. the bottom sheet includes input text field and three radios. when i click on input text field, this error occurs:
[image]

*The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and

black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a

ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,

like a ListView.
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#86450 OVERFLOWING:
needs compositing
creator: Column ← DecoratedBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ←
NotificationListener ← DefaultTextStyle ←
AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#39284 ink renderer] ←
NotificationListener ← PhysicalModel ← AnimatedPhysicalModel ←
Material-[GlobalKey#6e766 BottomSheet child] ← ⋯
parentData:  (can use size)
constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, h=185.0)
size: Size(360.0, 185.0)
direction: vertical
mainAxisAlignment: start
mainAxisSize: max
crossAxisAlignment: center
verticalDirection: down*

**the code is:**

```
floatingActionButton: InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    // Sizer
    // Navigator.of(context).
    // Navigator.of(context)
    //     .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AddNote()));
    //  scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet((context) => null)
    _scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet(
      (context) => Container(
        height: 70.h,
        width: double.infinity,
        // Sizer
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          // shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          color: Color(pagesBackgroundColor),
          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Color(pagesBackgroundColor))],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(15),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
            // DraggableScrollableSheet(
            //   builder: (context,scrollableController) {
            // return

        
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 15.w,
                  // clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                  height: 1.5.w,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.h),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    // shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)),
                    color: Color(greyColor),
                    // boxShadow:[ BoxShadow(color: )],
                  ),
                  // child: const Divider(
                  //   thickness: 3,
                  // ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.w),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      "Add new note",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                      // strutStyle: ,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          //TODO make note text
          //max line == 4
          //using package AutoSizeText
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.h),
                  child: AutoSizeTextField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                    cursorRadius: Radius.circular(2.w),
                    // scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    cursorColor: const Color(accentColor),
                    controller: _textEditingController,
                    minLines: 1,
                    maxLength: 150,
                    maxLines: 4,
                    // smartDashesType: ,
                    // wrapWords: true,
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title:
                      Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.homeTodayTap),
                  leading: Radio(
                    value: 1,
                    groupValue: 1,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      // setState(() {
                      //   _site = value;
                      // });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.homeTomorowTap),
                  leading: Radio(
                    value: 2,
                    groupValue: 1,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      // setState(() {
                      //   _site = value;
                      // });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.homeSomeDayTap),
                  leading: Radio(
                    value: 2,
                    groupValue: 1,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      // setState(() {
                      //   _site = value;
                      // });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          // ],
          // );
          // }
        ]),
      ),
    );
  },
  // for icon shape
  child: Container(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
    height: 11.h,
    width: 10.h,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1.w)),
      color: const Color(accentColor),
    ),
    // add note icone
    child: Icon(
      Icons.add,
      color: Colors.white,
      size: 9.h,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put SingleChildScrollView under **Expanded** widget

```
return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(...),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: it worked!, thanks a lot. But why this is the solution, could you explain why?